# C++ virtual function simple example

Tags: c++

Trying to get a quick understanding of how `virtual` functions work and not sure why the code below doesn't print any output. As far as I know, since `moveMouth()` is `virtual`, it should use the version of `moveMouth()` in the `talk` class.

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 29, 2015
 *      Author: Admin
 */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class talk{

public:

    int a=5;
     void moveMouth(){
        cout <<"blah blah blah"<<endl;
    }
};

class person : public talk {

public:
    int id;
    person(int a): id(a) {

    }

    virtual void moveMouth(){
        //cout <<"word word word"<<endl;
    }


};

int main(){
    person* p = new person(0);
    p->moveMouth();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to declare the base class function as virtual function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no output because the virtual function mechanism allow for calling a child class' function via pointer or reference to the parent, not to call a parent's function from the child.

If you wanted that behavior then just don't declare a function at all in the child:

```
class person : public talk {

public:
    int id;
    person(int a) : id(a) {

    }

    //virtual void moveMouth(){
    //    //cout <<"word word word"<<endl;
    //}


};
```

This will print the output because the inherited function will be called.

---

Here is an example of the virtual function mechanism based on the code provided:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class talk{

public:

    int a = 5;
    virtual void moveMouth(){ // base function is virtual
        cout << "blah blah blah" << endl;
    }
};

class person : public talk {

public:
    int id;
    person(int a) : id(a) {

    }
     void moveMouth() override { // override is optional but confirms we're overriding 
        cout <<"I'm a person"<<endl;
    }
};

class dog : public talk {

public:
    int id;
    dog(int a) : id(a) {

    }
     void moveMouth() override { // override is optional but confirms we're overriding 
        cout <<"I'm a dog"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    talk* p = new person(0);
    talk* d = new dog(0);
    p->moveMouth();
    d->moveMouth();

    std::vector<talk*> talkers; // can store pointers to all the different talkers in a single structure
    talkers.push_back(p);
    talkers.push_back(d);
    for(auto i : talkers)
        i->moveMouth();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I know, since `moveMouth()` is `virtual`, it should use the version of `moveMouth()` in the `talk` class.

No, that's not how polymorphism works. It allows you to introduce different behavior in the derived class when used in the base class.

Your example calls the empty implementation of `moveMouth()` from the `person` class.

To call the base class version just omit the declaration in the derived class:

```
class person : public talk {
public:
    int id;
    person(int a): id(a) {

    }

    // Completely omit this if you want to call the base class function by default:
    // virtual void moveMouth(){
        //cout <<"word word word"<<endl;
    // }
};
```

---

To allow to change the behavior, you must declare the function as `virtual` in the base class:

```
class talk{

public:

    int a=5;
     virtual void moveMouth(){
  // ^^^^^^^
        cout <<"blah blah blah"<<endl;
    }
};
```

The polymorphic behavior in the inheritance hierarchy starts from the point you first introduce a `virtual` function.

---

As an aside:
Polymorphic behavior can be better demonstrated like this

```
int main(){
    talk* t = new person(0);
    t->moveMouth();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the base class the virtual functions.

i.e. change the code to this

```
class talk{

public:

    int a=5;
    virtual void moveMouth(){
        cout <<"blah blah blah"<<endl;
    }
};
```

As an aside, `int a..` should be private - look up encapsulation

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the base class (talk) function `virtual`:

```
virtual void moveMouth(){
    cout <<"blah blah blah"<<endl;
}
```

override it in derived class (Person):

```
void moveMouth() override {
    cout <<"word word word" << endl;
}
```

and instead of `person* p = new person(0);` use the base class pointer to a derived class:

```
talk* p = new person(0);
```

to utilize the polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you must declare a method as `virtual` in the first class you want it to be `virtual`.

In addition, `virtual` invokation makes sense when you have a pointer or reference to an ancestor in the hierarchy of classes. If you already have a `person*` then in your case it's already `person::talk` with no other lookups.